# (Done) Reopen the question about interview test being free work

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

Reopen request for: [Huge interview test seems like real (free) work for the company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124554/huge-interview-test-seems-like-real-free-work-for-the-company)

This is marked as a duplicate of two questions that seem pretty different except for two words which are the same in the title. Can it be reopened?

And can the people who keep closing questions because they contain the same topic stop doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can it be reopened?

This question is now open again.